# Error when I push notification using firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**When I push notification from fore base I faced this error**

> E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
>       02-26 21:00:38.035 1328-1328/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
>       02-26 21:00:38.035 2145-2256/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
>       02-26 21:00:38.039 2145-2256/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
>       02-26 21:00:38.039 2145-2256/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>       02-26 21:00:38.040 2145-2256/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded

This is the on receive method

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: `E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296  `is clear what it means, all other messages are related to the first one